# Is there any cleanup that needs to be done for joined threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

Consider the following trivialized example:

```
import threading

def test():
    print ("In thread %r" % threading.current_thread())

while True:
    t = threading.Thread(target=test)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

For this program, is there any further cleanup step I should take after joining each `t`?  This script is meant to run forever and I want to ensure it doesn't just eat resources.
I do not spawn threads *this* quickly in the real application, but they do add up fairly quickly (around 200 per minute).

Comment: I've been running the above for about five minutes (up to `Thread-600000`) with no visible slow-down.

Comment: in this simple case, you shouldn't even need to join them!

Comment: @AdamSmith Of course, but in the real application, these threads could take up to three minutes each in the worst case.

Comment: Is there some reason you're spawning individual threads rather than using a thread pool?

Comment: @AdamSmith ignorance, probably – but these threads are just shell commands that must be run in order. It's not just a pool of work to be done.

Comment: Okay better question: if they must be run in order, why are you threading them?

Comment: @AdamSmith Because I need to be able to time them out. Some of these commands just hang and do not respond to signals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67497/discussion-between-adam-smith-and-sean-allred).

Comment: @AdamSmith I explained the backstory of this question in further detail in the chatroom, but the question stands regardless of the backstory.  I'm familiar with the X--Y problem, but this is far removed from the solution I'm using and is generally applicable to all applications that use threading in Python.